# How to use #ifdef for data type switching

Tags: c++, c, macros, typedef, type-conversion

I am using visual studio c++. I want to be able to switch between double and long long.
How can I use #ifdef in the following program? I want to use a more simpler solution to handle the case of multiple printf.

```
//#define TYPE_SWITCH
#ifdef TYPE_SWITCH
      typedef double myType;
#else
      typedef long long myType;
#end

.
.
.
int main()
{
     myType a;
     #ifdef TYPE_SWITCH
        printf ("my value is %lf",a);      // I have many printf or scanf and I want to use a simple macro here
     #else
        printf ("your value is %l",a/10);      // I have many printf or scanf and I want to use a simple macro here
     #endif

}
```

Comment: What is the underlying problem you are trying to solve? Also [**`switch`**](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/keyword/switch) is a keyword and a bad choice for a macro.

Comment: Thanks. I changed it to Iswitch

Comment: The correct C++ approach would be to use streams instead of `printf`/`scanf`, of course. Then the compiler would infer the correct type for you.

Comment: Please note I want to divide a when Iswitch is off.

Comment: Is this C++? Or C? The approaches are likely to be different in each. Again, it will depend on the underlying problem, which is not at all clear from the question.

Comment: That's C. I have used printf instead of cout.

Comment: OK. I'm trying to improve the question.

Comment: The "divide by 10" issue would be solved in C++ by an overload pair `read(std::istream&, double&)` and `read(std::istream&, long long&)`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use something like that:

```
//#define TYPE_SWITCH
#ifdef TYPE_SWITCH
      typedef double myType;
      #def PATTERN_MY_TYPE "%lf"
      #def MODIFICATOR(a) (a)
#else
      typedef long long myType;
      #def PATTERN_MY_TYPE "%l"
      #def MODIFICATOR(a) (a/10)
#end
#def PATTERN_INT "%d"

//...

int main() {
     myType a;
     printf(PATTERN_MY_TYPE ", " PATTERN_INT, MODIFICATOR(a), 42);
}
```

The compeiler can concate strings while compeiling so you can use `"foo" "bar"` to create the string `"foobar"` the same works for defines. (`"foo" PATTERN_INT "bar"` would produce `"foo%dbar"`.

Comment: See my edit that should work. Hint: The compiler will concate the strings correctly.

Comment: My edit supports this. I don't understand your problem... `printf ("SSE/IL: " PATTERN_MY_TYPE " > " PATTERN_MY_TYPE "\n", ts, ts/SST*100);`. Here is your code together with my pattern.

Comment: Can you please rename this thing to not be a keyword?

Comment: Please see my edit in the original post. I mean I want a more simpler macro to handle and get me rid if multiple #ifdef. Please note I have multiple patterns and variables after patterns are different.

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes what do you mean? remo why do you need to devide the value on a second type?

Comment: That is due to my application. I want to use long long to do faster calculations when possible (using Iswitch). But, this leads the result to be multiplied by a factor (for simplicity, I used a constant here)

Comment: Would you please let me know how C handles multiple patterns and concatenate them in printf! It's interesting for me after about 10 years of C/C++ learning :(

Comment: Your are welcome. @R.MartinhoFernandes now I got the point. Fixed.

Comment: Please rename switch to another non-keyword literal